# Normal Distribution of a randomly selected sample

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> Suppose the score of each student in an exam follows a Normal distribution with mean $\mu=75$ and standard deviation $\sigma=0.8$. If we take a random sample of 20 of these students, then what is the probability that more than 2 students will score less than 74.4

I know that for a sample size $n$, the mean of the random sample remains the same ($\mu$) as the population but the standard deviation becomes $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.

The thing which is confusing me here is this part: **probability that more than 2 students will score less than 74.4**

If they would have asked about the probability of the mean score of the 20 randomly selected samples being less than 74.4, then the solution was simple. This is what I would have done

$$
z = \frac{74.4-75}{\frac{0.8}{\sqrt{20}}}=-3.354 \\
P(z<-3.354) = 0.0004
$$

But how to deal with the situation which is asked in the original question. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the scores $X_1,\ldots,X_{20}$ of the students are independent and consider the random variables
$$Z_k = \begin{cases}0,\quad &{\rm if}\ X_k \geq 74.4,\\ 1,\quad &{\rm if}\ X_k < 74.4,\end{cases}$$
for $k=1,\ldots,20$. Then $Z_k$ all have identical [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with $p= P(X_k < 74.4)$ (from the computational point of view it's better not to use the tabled value yet). The probability that you're looking for is equal to the probability that $Z = Z_1 + \ldots + Z_{20} > 2$. Since $Z$ is a sum of identically distributed Bernoulli variables, it has [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $B(20,p)$. We have
$$P(Z>2) = 1-P(Z\leq 2).$$
The binomial distribution has an explicit CDF (see the link), can you proceed from here?

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks a ton :) Upvoted!

Comment: I think (maybe I am incorrect) that there will be just a small change in your otherwise correct implementation. $p=P(X_k < 74.4)$ and the value of $Z_k$ must be $0$ if $X_k \geq 74.4$ and $1$ otherwise because the question asks for "the probability that more than 2 students will score less than 74.4".

Comment: Yes, that's right!